# Android-How to create a new writeable file?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a jobIntentService that create a file to add some text in it but I get the error `/data/user/0/com.example.projet/files/log.txt (Is a directory)`. I don't know what I did wrong...
Here is my code :

```
public void ecritureLog(Context context) {

        File path = context.getFilesDir();
        File file = new File(path, "log.txt");

        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Debug ecriture log", "exeption levée : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            stream.write("text-to-write".getBytes());
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Debug ecriture log", "exeption levée : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Furthermore, what I want is a sort of log file so I want to access it from the phone but `/data/user/0/com.example.projet/files/log.txt` is an hidden path to the user...
I already tried `Environment.getDataDirectory()` but I don't have the permission even if they are in the manifest...

Edit : Here is my manifest permissions :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file

Comment: for file read and write you need to add run to permissions.

Comment: @Stultuske The problem is actually not the writting part but the creation part, because log.txt is seen as a directory and not as a file I cannot write in it...
The article you gave me just recap what I have done for the writing part...

Comment: @ahmadbajwa I already have ```READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE``` & ```WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE```. I don't know wich one is missing...

Comment: runtime means add java code from these permissions.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-how-to-create-a-file

Comment: `if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory() ) { if (!file.delete()) return;}`  Probably you created it as directory long time ago while experimenting... You do not need a single permission for getFilesDir(). If you want to let the user see the logfiles using a file manager then for devices below Android 11 use getExternalFilesDir() instead. No permissions needed. No runtime code needed either.

Comment: `if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();`...`Remove all that code. It is not needed. new FIleOutputStream() will create the file and delete an existing one first. Make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all the comment of you guys this work so there is the final code :

```
public void ecritureLog(Context context) {

        File path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
        File file = new File(path, "/log.txt");

        if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory() ) {
            if (!file.delete()){
                Log.d("Debug ecriture log", "!file.delete()");
                return;
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Log.d("Debug ecriture log", "chemin: " +file.getAbsolutePath());
            stream.write("text-to-write".getBytes());
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Debug ecriture log", "exeption levée : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Thanks !